# Powershell Script for Creating a Rule to Send LDAP Attributes as Claims on AD FS

Tags: powershell, saml, adfs, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to write script for adding rule like in the following [Microsoft documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8y1e.png)

that will work for Microsoft Server 2012 R2. Unfortunately I could not find any solution that works on this version (like Add-AdfsLocalClaimsProviderTrust for windows server 2016). Is there really no way to write script for sending LDAP attributes as claims on AD FS?

At the end the rule suppose to look like this:
[image: Edit Rule]

Comment: What is the question exactly? `Add-AdfsLocalClaimsProviderTrust` is still there in the 2016 version of the ADFS module

Comment: I need to do the following action on Microsoft Server 2012R2 and it is not supported

Answer (score 0):

Not all cmdlets are available in all OS versions and that cmdlet is simply not available in Server 2012R2. So, not really a support thing, it's just not there.

```
Get-Command -Name Add-AdfsLocalClaimsProviderTrust
```

Your have the option of using GUI automation via say ...[selenium-powershell](https://github.com/adamdriscoll/selenium-powershell) or using the PowerShellGallery A[DFSToolbox](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ADFSToolbox/1.0.3) module.

Note
I've not tried this with these two options, but I've used them for other things.